# WPF datagrid not fetching hexadecimal values properly, it displays a message Byte[] Array for hexadecimal Values?

Tags: wpf, hex, wpfdatagrid

WPF datagrid is not fetching hexadecimal values properly, it displays a message `Byte[]` Array for hexadecimal Values?

Do I need to change anything in the coding?

Comment: you need a converter for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it using a converter:

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="ByteArrayHex.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ByteArrayHex"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:ByteArrayToHexConverter x:Key="ByteArrayToHexConverter" />
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <TextBlock Margin="5" Text="{Binding ba, Converter={StaticResource ByteArrayToHexConverter}}" Background="Beige" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Data;

namespace ByteArrayHex
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public byte[] ba { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ba = new byte[] { 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D };
            this.DataContext = this;
        }
    }

    public class ByteArrayToHexConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            byte[] ba = value as byte[];
            if (ba == null)
                return null;
            SoapHexBinary shb = new SoapHexBinary(ba);
            return shb.ToString();
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```